# Spring execute method every 15 minutes

Tags: java, spring, cron

I tried to use cron expression from this site http://www.cronmaker.com/

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *")
public void clearRps() {
            
}
```

But it throws: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'clearRps': Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 7 in "0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *")

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just use the following cron:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * *")
```

Spring cron expression syntax slightly differs from unix cron expression. One immediate difference - it supports 1 less field (6 rather than 7).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 * * * ?")
```

In springboot i used this!